# Differential Equation for the spread of rumors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(t)$ be the number of people who have heard the rumor at time *t* and assume that everyone who has heard the rumor passes it to *r* others in unit time. Thus, from time *t* to time *(t+h)* the rumor is passed on *hry(t)* times, but a fraction of the people have heard it already, thus there are only $hry(t) \left(\frac{K-y(t)}{K}\right)$ people who hear the rumor for the first time. Make and expression for $y(t+h)-y(t)$, divide by *h*, and take the limit as $h \rightarrow 0$ to obtain a differential equation satisfied by y(t).

$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{y(t+h)-y(t)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{hry\left(\frac{K-y}{K}\right)-y}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{hry\left(\frac{K-y}{K}\right)\left[1 -\frac{1}{hr\left(\frac{K-y}{K}\right)}\right]}{h}$

$=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}ry\left(\frac{K-y}{K}\right)\left[1 -\frac{1}{hr\left(\frac{K-y}{K}\right)}\right]$

I've been at this for a while now, and I can't find a way to simplify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are only $hry(t) \left(\frac{K-y(t)}{K}\right)$ people who hear the rumor for the first time.

This counts the *new people* aware of the rumor hence this does not mean that
$$
y(t+h)=hry(t) \left(1-\frac{y(t)}{K}\right),
$$ but that
$$
y(t+h)=y(t)+hry(t) \left(1-\frac{y(t)}{K}\right),
$$
hence $y$ solves a [logistic differential equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function), namely,
$$
y'(t)=ry(t) \left(1-\frac{y(t)}{K}\right).
$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.